# How to extract the crystal symmetry from VASPs POSCAR/CONTCAR file?

Tags: crystallography, symmetry

VASPs POSCAR/CONTCAR file does not contain any direct information about the cell symmetry. If I run for example a calculation on simple TiN in space group 225, this symmetry is (should be) preserved. In other cases this is not so clear, so I would like to have a tool to extract the space group from a given structure file. A google search turned up a post on the VASP forum with the same question, but only unsatisfying answers - a commercial software package (Material Studio) and a now defunct link.

VESTA can impose a certain symmetry on a structure, but that is for entering lattice parameters, not for detecting present symmetry.

So I am asking now what simple, freely available tool can give me that information, preferably as a python package or similar.

Comment: The spglib module in ASE can likely do this, I don't have time to write up an answer yet though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple programs that can do this. As far as I know, all the open source codes use the excellent [spglib](https://spglib.github.io/spglib/) package by Atsushi Togo "under the hood" for space group perception, symmetrization, etc.

- [pymatgen](https://pymatgen.org/pymatgen.symmetry.analyzer.html)
- [ASE](https://ajjackson.github.io/ase-tutorial-symmetry/)

I'll outline using the Avogadro v2 interface. (Avogadro v1 is very similar).

I loaded a rutile POSCAR:

[image: rutile crystal structure]

Now I go to perceive the space group:

[image: Avogadro menu for space group perception]

I'm done. There is no step 3, unless you want to change the tolerances:

[image: dialog of space group perception]